# Android ListView style - cycles in resource definitions

Tags: android, android-listview, android-styles

This code

```
<style name="listViewPrefs" parent="@android:Widget.ListView">
...
</style>
```

produces the following `Android Rescources Validation` error:

> Invalid parent reference: expected @style. There should be no cycles in
>   resource definitions as this can lead to runtime exceptions.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use like,

```
<style name="listViewPrefs" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
...
</style>
```